# patterns for masking a XSS url to test against

Tags: url, xss, validation

I'm going to allow users to set an image with a link on my site. e.g. a profile picture and a profile link.

I will not let them upload said image, but let them give an url that i will insert into a img src.

I want to do basic checks for the best know xss patterns someone may use my site for, but thing is, i have no list of samples to check my functions works. As it is, even if I write a full RFC compliant parser to check every aspect of the URL, i will still not know what i should guard against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the following

- Check that the URIs start with http:// or https://
- URI encode the URI before printing it on the img src.

The first one is to make sure no javascript:, vbscript: etc. URLS are allowed. The second one is to escape any character that can cause damage (like ", ', <, > etc.).

Still a good resource for pattern, though a bit dated: http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html
Another great resource: http://html5sec.org

Answer (score 1):

Scan it using the [OWASP Zed Attack Proxy](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project) (ZAP).

ZAP is a free open source security tool, and its very good at finding XSS vulnerabilities.

Simon (ZAP Project Lead)